Calculate prorate value with dax PBI
I need to calculate a prorate value with dax.
I have 2 tables:
calendar table : contains dates and days worked



date
days worked




01/04/2024
0


02/04/2024
1


03/04/2024
1


04/04/2024
1


05/04/2024
1


06/04/2024
0


07/04/2024
0


08/04/2024
1


09/04/2024
1


10/04/2024
1


11/04/2024
1



In the month of April we have 21 working days
objective table: contains the objective values by date.



obj date
obj




05/04/2024
200


06/04/2024
150


07/04/2024
50


10/04/2024
300


12/04/2024
788


15/04/2024
450


16/04/2024
325


18/04/2024
6510


19/04/2024
20


22/04/2024
241


24/04/2024
178



I need to calculate the prorate of the current month:
divide ((sum(obj) , sum(days worked))*sum(days worked from the first day of the month to today)
for this exemple :

sum(obj) = 6212
sum(days worked) in the month  = 21
sum(days worked) from first day to today = 20

divide (6212 , 21)*20 = 5916,19

Can you provide more data ? I think there are some missing dates in the objective table.
How are you calculating sum(obj) to get 6212 ?

Is this something you are looking for? I have created a new measure called ProRate_02, that basically uses the filter context of a given month (you can also select one month or the current month) to calculate the pro-rated objective value based on the number of working days in a month versus the number of days that have actually passed.
ProRate_02 = 
VAR ObjectiveSum = SUM(ObjTable_02[Obj])
VAR TotalWorkingDays = SUM(CalendarTable_02[Days worked])

-- Get full days worked
VAR CurrentDay = TODAY()
VAR _EndOfMonth = MAX(CalendarTable_02[Date])
VAR MonthComplete = IF(CurrentDay > _EndOfMonth, 1, 0)

VAR FullDaysWorked = 
    IF(MonthComplete,
        TotalWorkingDays,
        CALCULATE(SUM(CalendarTable_02[Days worked]), FILTER(CalendarTable_02, CalendarTable_02[Date] < CurrentDay))
    )
RETURN DIVIDE(ObjectiveSum, TotalWorkingDays) * FullDaysWorked

The measure works as follows:

ObjectiveSum: This variable captures the total objective from ObjTable_02 for the current filter context.
TotalWorkingDays: This sums up the total working days from CalendarTable_02 for the month.
Current Day Calculation: Determines today's date.
Month Completion Check: Checks if the current day is beyond the last day of the month to determine if the month is complete.
Working Days Passed: If the month isn't complete, it recalculates the working days excluding today. This latter is an assumption that you do not want to include the current working day until it is passed.
Final Calculation: The prorated objective is then calculated by dividing the total objective by the total number of working days and multiplying by the full days worked to date

Additional information:

I have added some dummy data for March 2024 and used a 1-1 relationship between the Objective table and the calendar table. Perhaps there is a possibility to use a disconnected table, or just merge the objective table together with the calendar table if it remains a 1-1 relationship.
I also included a calculated column to get a YEARMONTH variable for the table visual.

My results:
Table with results
My tables:
CalendarDateTable
ObjectiveTable
My datamodel: data model
